# Read binary data in R instead of unpack in python

Tags: r

I learned python for  8 months,newbie to R,there is a binary file ,i can read
and change the binary data into a list (in python ,array is list).
the data file (named test )  is in:
https://www.box.com/s/0g3qg2lqgmr7y7fk5aut
Structure is:
Every 4 bytes is a integer,so to read it with unpack in python

```
import struct
datafile=open('test','rb')
data=datafile.read(32)
result=[]
while  data:
    result.append(list(struct.unpack('iiiiiiii',data)))
    data=datafile.read(32)
```

How can i read the binary data in R?

### I benefited from  Paul Hiemstra's help to finish the code in R.

```
datafile="test"
totalsize=file.info(datafile)$size
lines=totalsize/32
data=readBin("test",integer(),n=totalsize,size=4,endian="little")
result=data.frame(matrix(data,nrow=lines,ncol=8,byrow=TRUE))
colnames(result)=c(date,"x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6","x7")
```

There is still problem i want to solve.
Here ,i read all data totally with n=totalsize,if the data is huge ,the memory is not enough to contain ,how to express :to read data from the 1001th to 2000th byte?
If n=1000,it means to read data from 1th to 1000th,if n=2000,it means to read data form 1th to 2000th, how about to read data from 1001th to 2000th? Is there file pointer in R?when i read 1000th binary data,the file pointer is on the 1000th position,now to use command readBin("test",integer(),n=1000,size=4,endian="little") to read data from 1001th to 2000th?

Comment: Try and polish your language, primarily the lack of capital letters, and the incorrect use of commas and such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Googling for `R read binary file` yields [the following link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/read_binary.htm) as its first result. The bottom line is to use the `readBin` function, which in your case would look something like:

```
file2read = file("test", "rb")
number_of_integers_in_file = 128
spam = readBin(file2read, integer(), number_of_integers_in_file, size = 4)
close(file2read)
```

---

If you do not know the number of integers in the file, you can do a number of things, first create an example file:

```
# Create a binary file that we can read
l = as.integer(1:10)
file2write = file("/tmp/test", "wb")
writeBin(l, file2write)
close(file2write)
```

One strategy is to overestimate the number of integers to read readBin will only return the numbers that really exist. A vector the size of `n` is preallocated, so take care with making this too large.

```
file2read = file("/tmp/test", "rb")
l_read = readBin(file2read, integer(), n = 100)
close(file2read)
all.equal(l, l_read)
[1] TRUE
```

Alternatively, if you know the size, e.g. 4 bytes, of the numbers, you can calculate how many are present using the following function I wrote:

```
number_of_numbers = function(path, size = 4) {
  # If path is a file connection, extract file name
  if(inherits(path, "file")) path = summary(path)[["description"]]
  return(file.info(path)[["size"]] / size)
 }
number_of_numbers("/tmp/test")
[1] 10
```

In action:

```
file2read = file("/tmp/test", "rb")
l_read2 = readBin(file2read, integer(), n = number_of_numbers(file2read))
close(file2read)
all.equal(l, l_read2)   
[1] TRUE
```

---

If the amount of data is too big to fit in memory, I would recommend reading in chunks. This  can be done using consecutive calls to `readBin`, for example:

```
first_1000 = readBin(con, integer(), n = 1000)
next_1000 = readBin(con, integer(), n = 1000)
```

If you want to skip parts of the datafile, say the first 1000 numbers, use the `seek` function. This is much faster than reading 1000 numbers, discarding those, and reading the second 1000 numbers. For example:

```
# Skip the first thousand 4 byte integers
seek(con, where = 4*1000)
next_1000 = readBin(con, integer(), n = 1000)
```

Comment: `readBin("test",integer(),n=1,size=4,endian="little")`can get the right result as python,the first data(which contain 4 bytes)is `20070702`,but i still have question?how can i know the length of binary file?i can use parameter `n` to move `file pointer',let `n` increase until the end of the file.

Comment: Even more details in regard to your question of reading in chunks